# How to solve $f(y)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{p\cos (y) - qy} \,dy$

Tags: integration

Solving this integral $f(y)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{p\cos(y)-qy}\, dy$ is related to the double Laplace transform. where p, q are complex number frequency parameters. $p=\sigma_1 +i\omega_1$ ,$q=\sigma_2 +i\omega_2$ with real numbers σ and ω. p and q are similar to s in Laplace transform. p is related to x and q is related to y.

First of all, is it possible to directly bring $q=\sigma_2 +i\omega_2$ into the integral solving during the Laplace transform. That is the following form, $f(y)=\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{p\cos(y)-(\sigma_2 +i\omega_2)y}\, dy$. In this case, it seems that s of Laplace transform disappeared. However, it is advantageous that the form of this integral is closer to the Bessel function, which is $J_a(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i(at-xsint)}\, dt$

Secondly, if the above method is incorrect, how should this integral be solved? I guess the final result, if any, will still be related to the Bessel function.

Comment: Well, most integrals cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions... what makes you think this can?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Well, I think the form of this integral is somewhat close to Bessel  integrals. I think is it possible to express the value of this integral using Bessel integrals?

Comment: Note that if $q = 0$, the integral can be written as $I = 2\pi I_0(p)$.

Comment: I suspect that if $q = ki$ where $k \in \mathcal{Z}$, the integral can be evaluated in term of Bessel functions.